# Django Admin ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, manytomanyfield, django-orm

I've made a model (models.py):

```
class opetest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author')
    description = models.TextField(u'Test description', help_text = u'Some words about quiz')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', blank=False)
    vacancies = models.ManyToManyField(Vacancy, blank=True)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='opetests') #This field I want to edit on "User change page"
    estimate = models.IntegerField(default = 0, help_text = u'Estimate time in hours. \'0\' - unlimited')
```

then I try to add inline block to allow assign `opetest` on 'change user' page (admin.py):

```
class ProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('opetests',)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, ProfileAdmin)
```

And I got an error:

```
'ProfileAdmin.filter_horizontal' refers to field 'opetests' that is missing from model 'User'.
```

I want to show opetests like *Groups* on *change user* page. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If the answer below answered your question, can you please tick it? If it didn't, please let us know what else you need, and we can try and help.

Answer (score 81):

Hmm, I don't think you want inlines here.

You want to be using the Django admin's filter_horizontal:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal

```
class ProfileAdmin(UserAdmin)
    filter_horizontal = ('opetest',)
```

That will give you the widget that you're describing, used to add/remove Groups on the User Change page.

---

Ok, based on your edits, updated answer - basically, what we have is a UserProfile, linked to each user.

The UserProfile contains a m2m relationship to opetest - which we show in the admin with a filter_horizontal. End result is something like this:

[image: Opetest with Filter horizontal]

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class opetest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author')
    description = models.TextField(u'Test description', help_text = u'Some words about quiz')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', blank=False)
    #vacancies = models.ManyToManyField(Vacancy, blank=True)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='opetests') #This field I want to edit on "User change page"
    estimate = models.IntegerField(default = 0, help_text = u'Estimate time in hours. \'0\' - unlimited')

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    ope = models.ManyToManyField(opetest)
    test_flag = models.BooleanField()
```

`admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from secondapp.models import UserProfile, opetest

admin.site.unregister(User)

class opetestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    filter_horizontal = ('ope',)

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    #filter_horizontal = ('user_permissions', 'groups', 'ope')
    save_on_top = True
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'last_login')
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]

admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(opetest, opetestAdmin)
```

Let me know if you have any questions, or need anything further.

Comment: filter_horizontal parameters should refer to model fields. But opetest here is a model.

Comment: Hmm, why don't you create the `opetest` field on UserProfile, and have that map to `opetest`? It's a m2m field, so it shouldn't really matter which end of the relationship it's on - then you can just use `filter_horizontal` on the `opetest` field?

Comment: Sorry Victor, can you please describe, how can I create field on UserProfile and map it to opetest?

Comment: So, I've added field but it doesn't work:

'class ProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):'
'usertests = models.ManyToManyField(opetest, blank=True)'

'ProfileAdmin.filter_horizontal' refers to field 'usertests' that is missing from model 'User'.'
    filter_horizontal = ('usertests',)

Comment: Hmm, can you edit your question, and paste your full `models.py` and `admin.py` please? I'm a bit confused about the previous text, as you have `class ProfileADmin(UserAdmin)`, which looks like `admin.py`, but then in the next line you define a model field. If you paste your full code, we can help you get it working easier.

Comment: it was an experiment because I don't know how to add field "on the fly" on ProfileADmin. Can you help me? So, I have 'start' models and rolled back the changes.

Comment: @baobee: What do you mean by "on the fly"? Do you mean dynamically at run-time? *confused*. If you paste your source code, and what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to help you more =).

Comment: Can it be used outside of django admin? I wanted to use it in an intermediate view I created which technically isn't an official admin view, I just add the url in get_urls.