# Django admin interface: using horizontal_filter with inline ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a Django model field that I'd like to inline. The field is a many-to-many relationship.  So there are "Projects" and "User profiles". Each user profile can select any number of projects.

Currently, I've got the "tabular" inline view working. Is there a way to have a "horizontal filter" so that I can easily add and remove projects from a user profile?

Please see the attached picture for an example.[image]

Here's the model code for the User Profile:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, blank=True, help_text="Select the projects that this user is currently working on.")
```

And the model code for a Project:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    application_identifier = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=ProjectType)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    principle_investigator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

And the admin code for the view:

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfile.projects.through
    extra = 0
    verbose_name = 'user'
    verbose_name_plural = 'users'

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'application_identifier', 'type', 'account', 'active')
    search_fields = ('name', 'application_identifier', 'account__name')
    list_filter = ('type', 'active')
    inlines = [UserProfileInline,]
admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem isn't from having inlines; it's from the way `ModelForm`s work, in general. They only build form fields for actual fields on the model, not related manager attributes. However, you can add this functionality to the form:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

class ProjectAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project

    userprofiles = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=UserProfile.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
            verbose_name='User Profiles',
            is_stacked=False
        )
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            if self.instance.pk:
                self.fields['userprofiles'].initial = self.instance.userprofile_set.all()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        project = super(ProjectAdminForm, self).save(commit=False)  
        if commit:
            project.save()

        if project.pk:
            project.userprofile_set = self.cleaned_data['userprofiles']
            self.save_m2m()

        return project

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProjectAdminForm
    ...
```

A little walkthrough is probably in order. First, we define a `userprofiles` form field. It will use a `ModelMultipleChoiceField`, which by default will result in a multiple select box. Since this isn't an actual field on the model, we can't just add it to `filter_horizontal`, so we instead tell it to simply use the same widget, `FilteredSelectMultiple`, that it would use if it were listed in `filter_horizontal`.

We initially set the queryset as the entire `UserProfile` set, you can't filter it here, yet, because at this stage of the class definition, the form hasn't been instantiated and thus doesn't have it's `instance` set yet. As a result, we override `__init__` so that we can set the filtered queryset as the field's initial value.

Finally, we override the `save` method, so that we can set the related manager's contents to the same as what was in the form's POST data, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks so much Chris! This worked like a charm the first time I tried it!

Comment: Code was working for me when i changed `userprofile_set` to `userprofile`. Very clean code. Thanks

Comment: Thanks!  This helped me a ton!  One change is that in Django 1.9 you have to add a field = [ ] to the meta section or you get an error.

Comment: Beautiful answer, I'll try to find out how to adapt it for many-to-many relationship with custom intermediary models as it does not work for these cases.

Comment: this answer is superb~! but I am just wondering, we can do filtering on the left side, is it possible to have filtering input on the right side too?

Answer (score 3):

A minor addition when dealing with a many to many relationship with itself. One might want to exclude itself from the choices:

```
if self.instance.pk:
        self.fields['field_being_added'].queryset = self.fields['field_being_added'].queryset.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
        self.fields['field_being_added'].initial = """Corresponding result queryset"""
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier solution, just add `filter_horizontal`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8043918/4191904):

```
class YourAdmin(ModelAdmin)
    filter_horizontal = ('your_many_to_many_field',)
```

Before:[image]

After:[image]

Comment: This doesn't work on InlineAdmin objects-- which are the subject of the question.