# Django Add ManyToMany Relationship to Admin User Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm using the django admin feature as the backend administration for my site. It seems to work perfectly, out of the box for my needs, except for one thing. One of my models has a many-to-many relationship with a User. Here is the model:

```
class Facility(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()     
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

I've gotten it to let me add users to the facility on the facility page, but since the Admin form is built in, I don't know how to modify it. I found something that looked like what I want on SO:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )

admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

I tried swapping out email for `facility` or `facilities` or `facilitys` , but it seemed pretty obvious that that wouldn't work, and of course it did not. Any one have any advice?

Comment: Have you looked into using an InlineModelAdmin? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: @schillingt I remember coming across that, but it did look like what I need. How can I use that here? I'm looking to put a multiple select drop down on the default admin User add/edit page.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for then. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11658199/1637351

Answer (score 1):

In django this feature names [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) or "back reference" in SQLAlchemy. As you can see in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects):

> If a model has a ForeignKey, instances of the foreign-key model will have access to a Manager that returns all instances of the first model. By default, this Manager is named FOO_set, where FOO is the source model name, lowercased.

So, in your case you should use `facility_set` or redefine `related_name` on `users`
ManyToMany field in `Facility` model.

BTW, [@schillingt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1637351/schillingt): suggestion to use `InlineModelAdmin` much more easy and elegant than anything else.