# How to show Many-to-Many Field on Django Admin Panel?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have 2 models, Product and Tag. The relation between product and tag is Many-to-Many Relationship.

How to show "tags" field on django admin panel? Currently the value is None when I am using the code below

**models.py**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
  CATEGORY = (
    ('Indoor','Indoor'),
    ('Outdoor','Outdoor'),
  )

  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
  price = models.FloatField(null=True)
  category = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=CATEGORY)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ['id','name','price','category','tags']
  list_display_links = ['name']
  
  def tags(self):
    return self.tags.name
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776235/many-to-many-fields-view-on-django-admin/25776280

See here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ['id','name','price','category','get_tags']
  list_display_links = ['name']
  
  def get_tags(self, instance):
    return [tag.name for tag in instance.tags.all()]
```

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'price', 'category', 'get_tags']
    list_display_links = ['name']

    def get_tags(self, obj):
        if obj.tags.all():
            return list(obj.tags.all().values_list('name', flat=True))
        else:
            return 'NA'
```

Refer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: This can be applied outside the admin?

Answer (score 1):

In Django 4.1 you don't need to pass the second param (instance of class), and can do smth like this:

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ['id','name','price','category','get_tags']
  list_display_links = ['name']
  
  def get_tags(self):
    return [tag.name for tag in instance.tags.all()]
```

Also, you can detalize this field, and add decorator `@admin.display` example for add title for django admin. More details in docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display