# django: ManyToManyField in admin site: how to manually add instances

Tags: python, django

I have the following class:

```
class Option(models.Model):    
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have another class which uses it:

```
class Type(models.Model):
   ''' more properties here ''' 
   options = models.ManyToManyField(Option, blank=True)
```

The idea would be that in django's **admin site** I would be able to manually add `Option` instances to a `Type`.

Now, I already created 4 instances of `Option` in the admin site.
When I go to the `Type` configuration, to `options`, all 4 instances are already there. I'd like that box to be empty and add them manually, because for every instance of `Type` the list should be different.

How can I do that? Something is telling me that I misunderstood `ManyToManyField`... :)

EDIT: Adding the `ModelAdmin` class for `Option`:

```
class OptionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    options = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Option.objects.all(), widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("verbose name", is_stacked=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the "options" instance from your Type model and create a new class:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option)
```

Then I'd create as much assignment rows as needed in order to attach options to a type. However it's quite difficult to manage manually in the admin site…

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with is from this post/question:

[Django Admin ManyToManyField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043881/django-admin-manytomanyfield)

Using

```
filter_horizontal = ('options')
```

inside the `TypeAdmin` class

does what I need!